# Trying to center text with drop shadow

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to center texte which have a drop shadow. But not with the CSS property. I'm using span et :before to make it cross browser. So, this is what it looks like:

The HTML:

```
<h3 title="Say hello to Stack Overflow"><span>Say hello to Stack Overflow</span></h3>
```

And the CSS:

```
h3 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 29pt;
    color: #fefefe;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
    color: blue;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

h3:before {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    content: attr(title);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
```

The problem is, when I try to center the h3 (with text-align), only the shadow part goes to the center ([here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Axiol/zLAcA/))

Would you have a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took out the `<span>` (which was not needed) and added the `:before` element to the original `h3` styles, this seems to work:

```
h3:before,
h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 29pt;
    color: #fefefe;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
    color: blue;
    width:100%; /* This was important for the :before content */
}

h3:before {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 4px;
    content: attr(title);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zLAcA/3/

**Note:** If you're going for cross-browser, don't use `rgba` - it's not well supported. Actually, `:before` doesn't have great support either - If you're going for progressive enhancement, try [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) <strike>- you will be able to use the `text-shadow` property in IE.</strike>

**Edit**: As great as CSS3PIE is, `text-shadow` is not a supported feature. If the shadow is important, you will still need a workaround. What you have currently is probably the best way, but will only work in IE8 because there is [no `:before` support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)  in previous versions. You could [try a filter](http://jsfiddle.net/hKMHV/5/) for IE, but good luck finding one that looks nice, sorry.

```
h3 { filter: DropShadow(Color=#d9d9d9, OffX=4, OffY=4, Positive=1); }
```

Comment: CSS3 PIE handle text-shadow? Because I only see box-shadow :/

Comment: Hey you're right, my mistake! Updated post. I hate IE so much.

Comment: No problem :) I've found a solution with a little jQuery plug-in : http://www.hintzmann.dk/testcenter/js/jquery/textshadow/

Answer (score 0):

As said on twitter : http://jsfiddle.net/zLAcA/2/

```
    h3 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 29pt;
        color: #fefefe;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        position: relative;
        color: blue;
        position:relative;
    }

    span {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }

    h3:before {
        display: block;
        padding: 4px;
        content: attr(title);
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        position:absolute;
    }
```

Just added some position to the shadow :)